# vue apexcharts: charts in component rendered directly without animation after get axios data from props

Tags: vue.js, axios, apexcharts

In the parent template, I call a component and pass the axios data:

```
// template
<myChart
 :pdata="axiosData"
/>

// script
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      axiosData,
    }
  }
  created() {
    axios.get('some-url')
      .then(response => {
        this.axiosData = response.data
      })
  }
}
```

Because the child component "**myChart**" rendered an empty chart before it receives the props data, so I updated the chart series in a watch:

```
// below code is implemented in component
// template
<vue-apex-charts
  type="donut"
  height="200"
  :series="mySeries"
  :options="myOptions"
/>

// script
export default {
  props: {
    pdata: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
       mySeries: [],
       myOptions: ...
    }
  },
  watch: {
    pdata(val) {
      this.mySeries= val
    },
  }
}
```

The data in chart is rendered without any animation - if I set a static series in data(), chart is rendered with animation.

I tried some API like ApexCharts.render(), ApexCharts.updateOptions(..), ApexCharts.updateSeries(..), but they all can't trigger the data animation after props data updated in **watch**.

So what is the best practice in such scenario? How to trigger the animation after get axios data from server...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution ...

Adding **v-if="pdata && pdata.length"** can trigger the animation after props data receviced.